# Show a 0.01 difference in rectangle position?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

Today i needed to visualize a large data set on screen by using doubles or floats to position elements. When using pixels i can simply draw a rectangle with the following code:

```
gimg.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(1, 1, 50, 50));
```

But when i try drawing two rectangles with the following code a problem appears.

```
gimg.setColor(Color.white);
gimg.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(1.0, 1.0, 50, 50));
gimg.setColor(Color.gray);
gimg.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(1.1, 1.1, 50.1, 50.1));
```

The 2 rectangles are drawn over each other, in other words, you can't see a white and a gray rectangle because the gray one is drawn over the white one.

I'm using a 0.1 increment. After a bit of testing i seem to be able to view partial rectangles when using a 0.5 increment. The problem here is only i also need to make rectangles visible which only differ 0.01 in position.

I suspect i'm missing something really important here. Can anybody offer me a helping hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using a 0.1 : 1 scale instead, because pixels can't be divided into tenths (or any fraction for that matter) without losing accuracy / presentability. Imagine the tiny pixels on your screen - you're trying to divide a 1px line into 10 *distinguishable* sections. That's not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i gave it some thought and indeed if i continue on yesterdays path i likely end up with a visualization that is very crowded and not clear. A better idea would be to generate subviews of the global overview. Lets give that some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't "split" pixels into fractions, you can draw rectangles with "blurred" lines which span 2 pixels. (Unfortunately, this will take more complicated code than what you are using right now.) In this case, though, I think you need to take a step back, and think about the characteristics of the data you are working with and what kind of meaning you want people to draw from that data.

Even if it was possible to position rectangles on the screen with micrometer precision, your users wouldn't be able to discern the meaning behind the data any better because *this* rectangle is 0.0001mm further to the right than *that* one.

Perhaps you need to find a better visualization than rectangles positioned at different locations on the screen. Maybe you can make use of varying colors, or intensity of color, to convey some aspects of the data. It's impossible to say anything more specific without knowing exactly what you are doing.